# What is the alternate of cv2.line() method in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, hough-transform

cv2.line() - used to draw a line.

My Environment:

- IDE: PyCharm
- Python Version: 3.6
- Windows 10

I am unable to install cv2 on pycharm.
Command used:

```
pip install cv2
```

Could anyone here suggest me an alternate of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download '**opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl**' OpenCV manually from below URL

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Open command Prompt and hit '**pip install opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl**'

It should work!